# How do I install TensorFlow's tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

How do I install TensorFlow's tensorboard?

Comment: you can do: `conda install -y -c conda-forge tensorboard`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The steps to install Tensorflow are here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/

For example, on Linux for CPU-only (no GPU), you would type this command:

```
pip install -U pip
pip install tensorflow
```

Since [TensorFlow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow) depends on [TensorBoard](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorboard), running the following command should **not** be necessary:

```
pip install tensorboard
```

Comment: have you tried it. i wasn't able to run tensorboard. now i have git-cloned the tensorflow repo and i'm trying to build bazel since this seems to be a requirement

Comment: @Alex_M Yes, that worked for me. TensorBoard was installed as part of Tensorflow, and I was able to run it using `python .local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/tensorboard.py --logdir=tmp`

Comment: @Alex_M: Any time you're able to run TensorFlow you should be able to run TensorBoard as well; if you pip installed then you can just use the `tensorboard` command, but running the tensorboard.py file under tensorflow/tensorboard should work as well.

Comment: totally curious. since i was running linux in a vm on windows, i organized today a ssd and installed linux on bare-metal. 
i pip installed tensorflow and I'm now not able to run tensorboard any more. "hich tensorboard" returns nothing

Comment: I find this answer misleading as ```tensorflow``` isn't needed for ```tensorboard```. Many other ML libraries use ```tensorboard``` for logging so I wouldn't state ```tensorflow``` as a requirement for ```tensorboard```. 

The correct and simpler response would be directly install tensorboard either with conda or pip, skipping the install of ```tensorflow```.

Comment: what about with conda?

Comment: you can do: `conda install -y -c conda-forge tensorboard`

Answer (score 37):

Try typing `which tensorboard` in your terminal. It should exist if you [installed with `pip`](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup#pip_installation) as mentioned in the [tensorboard README](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/README.md) (although the documentation doesn't tell you that you can now launch tensorboard without doing anything else).

You need to give it a log directory. If you are in the directory where you saved your graph, you can launch it from your terminal with something like:

```
tensorboard --logdir .
```

or more generally:

```
tensorboard --logdir /path/to/log/directory
```

for any log directory.

Then open your favorite web browser and type in `localhost:6006` to connect.

That should get you started. As for logging anything useful in your training process, you need to use the [TensorFlow Summary API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/summary). You can also use the [`TensorBoard` callback in Keras](https://keras.io/callbacks/#tensorboard).

Answer (score 14):

If your Tensorflow install is located here:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow
```

then the python command to launch Tensorboard is:

```
$ python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/tensorboard.py --logdir=/home/user/Documents/.../logdir
```

The installation from pip allows you to use:

```
$ tensorboard --logdir=/home/user/Documents/.../logdir
```

Comment: The path has changed slightly since this answer was written. It is now: `tensorflow/tensorboard/backend/tensorboard.py` (also, `pip show tensorflow` can be used to get the base directory for a particular machine)

Answer (score 11):

It may be helpful to make an alias for it.

Install and find your tensorboard location:

```
pip install tensorboard
pip show tensorboard
```

Add the following alias in .bashrc:

```
alias tensorboard='python pathShownByPip/tensorboard/main.py'
```

Open another terminal or run exec bash.

For Windows users, cd into `pathShownByPip\tensorboard` and run `python main.py` from there.

For Python 3.x, use `pip3` instead of `pip`, and don't forget to use `python3` in the alias.

Answer (score 8):

TensorBoard isn't a separate component. TensorBoard comes packaged with TensorFlow.

Comment: Now, it is separate: `pip install tensorboard`

Answer (score 4):

Adding this just for the sake of completeness of this question (some questions may get closed as duplicate of this one).

I usually use user mode for pip ie. `pip install --user` even if instructions assume root mode. That way, my tensorboard installation was in `~/.local/bin/tensorboard`, and it was not in my path (which shouldn't be ideal either). So I was not able to access it.

In this case, running

```
sudo ln -s ~/.local/bin/tensorboard /usr/bin
```

should fix it.

Answer (score 3):

```
pip install tensorflow.tensorboard  # install tensorboard
pip show tensorflow.tensorboard
# Location: c:\users\<name>\appdata\roaming\python\python35\site-packages
# now just run tensorboard as:
python c:\users\<name>\appdata\roaming\python\python35\site-packages\tensorboard\main.py --logdir=<logidr>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the anaconda distribution of Python, then simply do:

```
 $❯ conda install -c conda-forge tensorboard
```

or

```
 $❯ conda install -c anaconda tensorboard
```

---

Also, you can have a look at various builds by search the packages repo by:

```
$❯ anaconda search -t conda tensorboard
```

which would list the channels and the corresponding builds, the supported OS, Python versions etc.,

Comment: The man page for `conda install` says that the `-c` flag is ignored, what is up with that?

Comment: @xjcl If you type `man conda install` that doesn't open a man page for conda.

Comment: @xjcl it's definitively not ignored in my experience. That is odd. `-c conda-forge` seems to work most of the time for me.

Comment: @CharlieParker I might have opened the man page for `install` by accident, apologies

Answer (score 2):

If you installed TensorFlow using `pip`, then the location of TensorBoard can be retrieved by issuing the command `which tensorboard` on the terminal. You can then edit the TensorBoard file, if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The `pip` package you are looking for is `tensorflow-tensorboard` developed by Google.

Comment: This answer used to be accurate, but no longer is: the package is now simply called `tensorboard`, and `tensorflow-tensorboard` is defunct.

Answer (score 1):

It is better not to mix up the virtual environments or perform installation on the root directory. Steps I took for hassle free installation are as below. I used conda for installing all my dependencies instead of pip. I'm answering with extra details, because when I tried to install tensor board and tensor flow on my root env, it messed up.

- Create a virtual env

  `conda create --name my_env python=3.6`
- Activate virtual environment

  `source activate my_env`
- Install basic required modules

  `conda install pandas`

  `conda install tensorflow`
- Install tensor board

  `conda install -c condo-forge tensor board`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I have a local install of tensorflow 1.15.0 (with tensorboard obviously included) on MacOS.

For me, the path to the relevant file within my user directory is Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorboard/main.py.  So, `which` does not work for me, but you have to look for the file named main.py, which is weird since it apparently is named something else for other users.