# Issues: tensorboard: command not found

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard

My environment:

```
$ pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.4.1
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: tensorflow-tensorboard, mock, enum34, protobuf, wheel, backports.weakref, six, numpy
```

When I trying to run *tensorboard* there are no founds in terminal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install tensorboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33634008/how-to-install-tensorboard)

Comment: what command are you running to start tensorboard?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what OS you're on, but I'm on Ubuntu 17.10.

Installing tensorflow also installs an executable version of tensorboard in `~/.local/bin`. But in order to execute this file by calling it from the command line, there needs to be a symbolic link to the executable inside the directory `/usr/bin`. For some reason, installing tensorflow doesn't do it for you automatically.

I solved the issue by manually creating the symlink with this command:

`sudo ln -s ~/.local/bin/tensorboard /usr/bin`